# How to fit 3 pipes into 1 laundry box drain?

Tags: plumbing, drain, pipe, washing-machine, washer

I am trying to install an LG TwinWash washer + pedestal washer combo in a new 3-story townhome. Laundry room is on the 3rd floor. The 2-washer combo requires 2 drains. LG supplies a part to merge them into 1 drain. The installer said the existing drain fitting is special and he couldn't fit the LG drain part into it. Questions:

- What's the pipe on top of the laundry box for?
- How to fit 3 pipes into 1 laundry box drain?

Thanks!

[image: plumbing photo]